# Prove that the set of all isolated points of $A$ is countable

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a second countable topology space. Prove that the set of all isolated points of $A$ is countable ($A$ is an arbitrary subset of X).

I tried to relate the base which is countable to set of isolated points but I didn't find solution. Can you help me ?

Comment: By “separated points”, I presume you mean [*isolated* points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point)? (Also, it “sep**a**rated”, coming from Latin *separare*, meaning *to divide*.)

Comment: Yeah I mean isolated point, see my latest update

Answer (score 2):

Let $B_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a countable base. For each isolated point we know $\{x\}$ is open and hence a union of open basic sets this means that there is some $n(x)$ such that $B_{n(x)}=\{x\}$. Then $x \to n(x)$ is an injection from the set of isolated points of $X$ into $\mathbb{N}$, so the set is countable at most.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, let $x ∈ X$ be an isolated point. Then $\{x\} ⊆ X$ is open, that is: an open neighbourhood of $x$. So for any topological base of $X$, you’ll find in that base a nonempty neighbourhood of $x$ *within* $\{x\}$, right? Meaning …?

So by $X$ having a countable topological base, you’ll find …?